# Upper-bounds for a vector equation

Tags: norms

Let $a$, $c$, $d$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors, and $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are matrices. Suppose that $ v = Ac-d $, and $a = ABc- \|B\| d$ where $\| B \|$ is the maximum value of the norms of the eigenvalues of $B$.

Is it true that $\| a \| \leq \|B\| \| v\|$?

Comment: Do you really mean $\lVert B\rVert$ is the maximum eigenvalue, or the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues (which would be the operator norm)? E.g., if $B=-I$ (where $I$=identity), is $\lVert B\rVert=1$ or $\lVert B\rVert=-1$.

Comment: Oops, I modified it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not true in general.

Example: $A:=I$ (identity). $B:=-I$. $c\neq 0$ arbitrary. $d:=c$.

Then $v=Ac-d=0$ and $a=ABc-\lVert B\rVert d=-c-1d=-2c\neq 0$. Then $\lVert a\rVert > 0$ and $\lVert B\rVert\lVert v\rVert=0$.

Comment: So, you mean that $B = -I$, right? I understand that there exists an example. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the "$-$" got lost accidentally. I edited it now.